# syntax error, unexpected 'if'

Tags: php, html

I am hoping someone can help me with this syntax error, not sure how to fix it. I know I am missing something just not sure what it is.

I am getting a syntax error on this line. `$id = '<input type="text" value= " .' if(isset($_REQUEST['rid'])){`

Here's the full code

```
<?php 
require_once('./config.php');
require_once("../auth/config.class.php");
require_once("../auth/auth.class.php");

$config = new Config;

$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host={$config->dbhost};dbname={$config->dbname}", $config->dbuser,     $config->dbpass);
$auth = new Auth($dbh, $config);


    $id = '<input type="text" value= " .' if(isset($_REQUEST['rid'])){
     echo $_REQUEST['rid'];
     } '.
     "  name="patient" >';
    echo $id;



$query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT hours FROM svcrequest WHERE id=? ");
$query->execute(array($id));    
$rslt = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$cost    = ($rslt['hours'] * 23)*100;
echo $cost;


?>
```

Comment: That's not valid php syntax. Split it into separate statements or use a ternary expression for your `if` construction.

Comment: `echo '<input type="text" value="' . isset($_REQUEST['rid'])? $_REQUEST['rid'] : '' .'" name="patient" >';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a run-on line, and can fix it like this:

```
$id = '<input type="text" value="';
if(isset($_REQUEST['rid'])){
    $id .= $_REQUEST['rid'];
}
$id .= '" name="patient" >';
echo $id;
```